# ERROR util.ResourceLeakDetector: LEAK: ByteBuf.release() Connection.getTable().put(List)

Tags: java, java-8, memory-leaks, hbase, netty

I am trying to do a lot of PUTs in Hbase, however, after some time of operation, a memory leak occurs due to the following error:

ERROR util.ResourceLeakDetector: LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. See http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html for more information. Recent access records: #1: org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.buffer.AdvancedLeakAwareByteBuf.writeBytes(AdvancedLeakAwareByteBuf.java:616) org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.buffer.ByteBufOutputStream.write(ByteBufOutputStream.java:68) org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue.write(KeyValue.java:2313) org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValueUtil.oswrite(KeyValueUtil.java:805) org.apache.hadoop.hbase.codec.KeyValueCodec$KeyValueEncoder.write(KeyValueCodec.java:63) org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CellBlockBuilder.encodeCellsTo(CellBlockBuilder.java:192) org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CellBlockBuilder.buildCellBlock(CellBlockBuilder.java:171) org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CellBlockBuilder.buildCellBlock(CellBlockBuilder.java:155) org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcDuplexHandler.writeRequest(NettyRpcDuplexHandler.java:81) org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcDuplexHandler.write(NettyRpcDuplexHandler.java:119) org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:706) org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:753) org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:778) org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:747) org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:801) org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.writeAndFlush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1036) org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannel.java:305) org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcConnection.write(NettyRpcConnection.java:284) org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcConnection.access$1100(NettyRpcConnection.java:71) org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcConnection$6$1.run(NettyRpcConnection.java:344) org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404) org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:495) org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905) org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

I am using the `hbase-client` version - `2.2.3`

I tried to change the parameters recommended in the HBASE-19320 release, but it did not give results.

Comment: Format properly the error log. It is very difficult to read a mulitline log in a single line. Preserve the original formatting for readability

Comment: Please use [code format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for code, errors and logs. I didn't had the link at hand in my previous comment.